# ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(344)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process

Tags: raspbian, python, linux, chromium, kiosk

I am using a Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:        9.3
Codename:       stretch

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 60.0.3112.89 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 9.3
```

I want to run a python script whenever the Raspberry Pi boots up and also open the Chromium browser to interact with the user for the running python script. Here is how I do so:

In `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi` folder there is a file called `autostart` in which I added `@lxterminal` at the bottom of the file. This line opens terminal automatically whenever the Raspberry Pi boots up.

Then I added `python /home/pi/dev/server.py & chromium-browser --kiosk http://localhost:5000` at the bottom of the `.bashrc` file right before the last line. This runs my python script (which runs 3 Threads) **AND** opens chromium browser in fullscreen and opens http://localhost:5000 URL.

This whole thing makes my program to be run and do what I expect from it.
But there's a problem when the program starts to work. Ok, when my Raspberry Pi boots up, I get what I want and it works for a while, but then after a random time which varies from 30 seconds up to 10 minutes, I get the error.

```
- SocketIO and Flask [ONLINE] 
- Fingerprint worker [ONLINE] 
- RFID worker        [ONLINE] 
[1771:1771:0521/104736.708166:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(344)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
Connectc06902ecb4064b70842121b9789ad9c4
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_innerself.run()
...[Some Traceback]...
[1:8:0521/104851.968154:FATAL:memory_linux.cc(35)] Out of memory.
#0 0x000002157eb0 <unknown>
#1 0x00000216f210 <unknown>
#2 0x00000218f9ec <unknown>
#3 0x0000021e517c <unknown>
#4 0x00000284e2a4 <unknown>
#5 0x000002a10db4 <unknown>
#6 0x000002a114a8 <unknown>
#7 0x0000028a7878 <unknown>
#8 0x0000028a2820 <unknown>
#9 0x00000284a18c <unknown>
#10 0x00000284a5d0 <unknown>
#11 0x0000029eec9c <unknown>
#12 0x00000272089c <unknown>
#13 0x000002c3cefc <unknown>
#14 0x000002c3c4b8 <unknown>
#15 0x000002c3a8dc <unknown>
#16 0x000002c3a6c0 <unknown>
#17 0x000002f09d4c <unknown>
#18 0x000002f099bc <unknown>
#19 0x000002f090f0 <unknown>
#20 0x000002f06b20 <unknown>
#21 0x000002f360b4 <unknown>
#22 0x00000479de20 <unknown>
#23 0x00000479d200 <unknown>
#24 0x0000021bb930 <unknown>
#25 0x0000021b7948 <unknown>

Received signal 6
#0 0x000002157eb0 <unknown>
#1 0x000002157e20 <unknown>
#2 0x00007553f6c0 <unknown>
#3 0x00007553e45c gsignal
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
Disconnectc06902ecb4064b70842121b9789ad9c4
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve that?

Comment: *"Then I added python /home/pi/dev/server.py & chromium-browser --kiosk http://localhost:5000 at the bottom of the .bashrc"* -> That's not what `.bashrc` is for.  That this is an OOM error implies you're repeatedly spawning chromium instances via that, because `.bashrc` **may be run any number of times**.  It is not a system initialisation script, see INVOCATION in `man bash`.